# Keras Masking layer doesn't seem to be working properly

Tags: keras, keras-layer, masking

Keras Masking layer is not properly masking embedding output. Here is my code sample -

-- Input Data

```
    raw_inputs = [
        [711, 632, 71],
        [73, 8, 3215, 55, 927],
        [83, 91, 1, 645, 1253, 927],
    ]
    padded_inputs = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(
        raw_inputs, padding="post"
    )
    print(padded_inputs)
```

```
[[ 711  632   71    0    0    0]
 [  73    8 3215   55  927    0]
 [  83   91    1  645 1253  927]]
```

---Padding code

```
    from tensorflow.python.keras import layers
    embedding = layers.Embedding(input_dim=5000, output_dim=16)
    masked_output = embedding(padded_inputs)

    masking_layer = layers.Masking(mask_value=0.0)

    masked_embedding = masking_layer(masked_output)

    print(masked_embedding._keras_mask)
```

I get the following output -

```
tf.Tensor(
[[ True  True  True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True]], shape=(3, 6), dtype=bool)
```

Any idea why masking is not happening properly? All values with 0 should have been masked `False`.

Answer (score 1):

padded_inputs is already converted to masked_output with embedding in your code, and 0 in it is lost. Check the https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/masking/ for more info. You can also print your masked_output, and you will see that 0 does not exist.

In the original sample offered by tensorflow, you should either use

`embedding = layers.Embedding(input_dim=5000, output_dim=16, **mask_zero=True**)`

or

`unmasked_embedding = tf.cast( tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(padded_inputs, axis=-1), [1, 1, 10]), tf.float32 )`